# Template argument deduction when types are not in function prototype

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

According to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization, "When specializing a function template, its template arguments can be omitted if template argument deduction can provide them from the function arguments".

Is it every possible to provide an explicit type for specialisation when the type cannot be deducted?

Consider this basic example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
void print(int i) {
    T t = static_cast<T>(i) * static_cast<T>(1.5);
    cout << t << endl;
}

int main()
{
    print<double>(5);
    print<int>(5);

    return 0;
}
```

What if we wanted to provide a specialisation for a type, like `int` that does something different, even though `int` doesn't appear in the function prototype? e.g. I'm looking for a way to do something like this:

```
template<T = int>
void print(int i) {
    cout << i << endl;
}
```

Comment: The syntax is `template<> void print<int>(int i)`

Comment: I had to read twice and recheck the cppreference article. I think I understand where your confusion comes from. The section "Explicit specializations of function templates" appears to cover the general case of specializing a function template, but it starts with some exception, with a special case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A specialization looks like this:

```
template<>
void print<int>(int i) {
    cout << i << endl;
}
```

The sentence you read refers to the case

```
tempalte <typename T> void foo(T);
```

Where a specialization can be declared via a shorter

```
template <> void foo(int);
```

as an alternativ to the usual

```
tempalte <> void foo<int>(int);
```

The latter is ok in either case.

Comment: Yes stupid mistake by me...